# How to add table to Debezium Postgres connector

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

What should be the steps for adding a new table into a Postgres connector? my connector is tracking 2 tables (table1 and table2) and I want to add anther table (table3) that already exists and have data in my DB.

This is my current config:

```
{
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "database.dbname": "db_name",
    "database.hostname": "HOST_URL",
    "database.password": "$PASSWORD",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.server.name": "db_data",
    "database.sslmode": "require",
    "database.user": "user_replication",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "publication.autocreate.mode": "disabled",
    "table.include.list": "public.table1, public.table2"
},
"name": "db-to-kafka-source"
```

}

I have tried to modify the connector "table.include.list" and add "public.table3" to the list, but it doesn't seems to trigger the snapshot process for this table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

no the snapshot will not be triggered. This should be solved with ad-hoc snapshots planned for 1.6. In the meantime you can fire up a temprorary connector just to execut the snapshot of the new table and then resume the original one.

Comment: how to I stop the "new" connector after the snapshot? or can I set it to do just the snapshot?
So the process should be:
1. Stop the "old" connector
2. Start a new connector with only the new tables
3. Wait for it to snapshot all tables
4. Stop it (not sure how)
5. Modify the publication on Postgres to add the new tables
6. Restart the "old" connector
7. Update the connector tables list with the new tables
is that right or did I missed anything?

Comment: Could it also work in the other direction? meaning to if I set some tables in "table.exclude.list" and on the Postgres side, each time I add a new table I will also add it to the publication, will that allow "debezium" to track the new table or I will need to edit the connector? 
I understand that those are slightly different questions. Thanks for the help